# tag:* links incorrectly when using Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts

Tags: feature-request, tags, markdown, tag-links, cross-site-tags

The [css](/questions/tagged/css) tag in my Stack Exchange profile links to different sites depending on where it's being viewed:

- Profile on StackOverflow:

  - `[tag:CSS] => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css`
- Profile on StackExchange:

  - `[tag:CSS] => https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css`
- Profile on CodeReview:

  - `[tag:CSS] => http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css`

I'd like to have these all link to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css`. You can [manually specify the language of a code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting); why not add the ability to specify the site with tags?

```
<!-- tag: stackoverflow -->[tag:css] <!--tag: meta -->[tag:feature-request]
```

The current behavior also cause a bug on my [Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/247863/wex):

> [image]

All tags send me to find a Panda aka 404 Page Not Found.

Comment: That seems like a very over-complicated solution - just use the direct link to the tag. Is having it styled as a tag really *that* important? I believe this has come up before, where I stated that seeing a styled tag on a site *implies* that it goes to the tag *on that site*.

Comment: @animuson **YES**.

Comment: For the Stack Exchange profile, I think it should use the site that was used to get the profile from.

Comment: See also this handy-sounding userscript: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278421/145828 (don't worry, it isn't a userscripts.org link)

Comment: (Huh, I was expecting SE to strip out the "affiliate" part of that link.  I wonder why it didn't?)

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps this is a somewhat simpler solution:

```
[tag:stackoverflow:CSS]
```

So tags can either have the format `[tag:tagname]` or `[tag:sitename:tagname]`

Comment: That's actually... making perfect sense! I would go with shortcuts though e.g. `[so-tag:css]`. [so-tag:css] (just in case it'll ever be implemented)

Comment: I would be in favor of @Sha's solution. `[rpg-tag:tag]` `[gaming-tag:tag]` etc.