# Expand magic tag-links so all sites can be specified

Tags: feature-request, magic-links, tag-links

Apparently after the split, all the tag-links (once they are fixed) will point to MSE instead of SO.  It seems like many questions will want to reference tags on a particular site.  We already had the special magic tag link of `[meta-tag:]`, so how about a syntax to direct tag-links to the site of choice, or at least a subset of the sites that we can make easy abbreviations to?

Comment: Well, it was already suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172841/tag-links-incorrectly-when-using-save-and-copy-profile-to-all-stack-exchange-a).