# Add magic links for Meta Stack Overflow and other site metas for sites hosted on their own domains

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, magic-links

In comments here on Meta SE I can use the magic link `[so]` to link to https://stackoverflow.com.

Consequently, I would have expected the magic link `[meta.so]` to link to https://meta.stackoverflow.com but that magic link does not seem to be available.

Can it be added, please?

Comment: I think this specifc feature should be expanded into a broader request for more, more consistent magic links, but I would enjoy this as-is.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty @cat - I figure that this is the missing magic link with the highest profile so the best place to start asking for more.

Comment: Do magic links support linking to questions/answers?

Comment: @Moshe Not as far as I know; I use the **share** button beneath them to grab those links.

Comment: Given that you *can* already use e.g. `[meta.gaming.SE]` to link to [meta.gaming.SE], the fact that this *doesn't* work for the SOFU trilogy sites seems like a simple oversight that should be fixed.

Comment: @cat: I guess you didn't see what happened to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230398/expand-magic-tag-links-so-all-sites-can-be-specified ?

Comment: What's worse is that `[metaso]` links to Meta Stack Exchange and not to Meta Stack Overflow as you would expect.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I suspect that's due to that magic link being established before the meta April 2014 MSO-MSE split: prior to that, this site was known as Meta Stack Overflow (the current Meta.SO was newly established at that time).

Comment: Just testing whether some of the following works in comments (I have already tried that they [do not work in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1/2024/1/5)):
`[meta.so]` [meta.so] and `[so.meta]` [so.meta]
`[meta.sf]` [meta.sf] and `[sf.meta]` [sf.meta]
`[meta.su]` [meta.su] and `[su.meta]` [su.meta]
`[mathoverflow.meta.se]` [mathoverflow.meta.se] and `[meta.mathoverflow.se]` [meta.mathoverflow.se].
This one works: `[meta.ubuntu.se]` [meta.ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that this already works for every per-site meta *except* for meta.SO, meta.SU and meta.SF (and, presumably, meta.pt.SO and the other localized SO metas), I'm pretty sure that this is just a simple oversight that should be fixed.

(For example, typing `[meta.gaming.SE]` into a comment expands into a link to [Arqade Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/).  See [this comment above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/903549) for a live demonstration.)

Comment: I guess MathOverflow is another exception. `[mathoverflow.se]` gives [mathoverflow.se], but `[meta.mathoverflow.se]` does not work: [meta.mathoverflow.se].

Answer (score 8):

I agree with the [comment of 'cat'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274240/adding-magic-link-for-meta-stack-overflow#comment901404_274240) that this feature request would be great to have, but there is so much more to add to.

I would love to see the magic link feature work over the entire network in a consistent way. I would love to see these magic links implemented:

- `[main]`: this would link to the main site, so on Stack Overflow or Meta Stack Overflow it would like to http://stackoverflow.com.
- `[meta]`: this would link to the per-site meta site, so on Stack Overflow or Meta Stack Overflow it would like to http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

It this way you can link to any site within the own scope.

You could even take that further by assigning a code to every site so you can link the sites from another site in the network. So `so.` for Stack Overflow would make `[so.main]`. Seasoned Advice would be something like `[cooking.main]`.

Comment: Where do we define abbreviations? Is AskDifferent `ad` or `apple`? Commonly used names or sub domain?

Comment: @Moshe I would expect `[apple.se]` to expand to [apple.se], which it does, so try typing it into a comment to see that it works (once the comment is saved).

Comment: `[meta.main]` should link to meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 `[meta.se]` links to [meta.se]. `[metaso]` also does, which [doesn't make sense](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296795/349538).

Answer (score 7):

I've made a 'Magic links enhancer' userscript to make magic links more useful across all SE sites.

It uses [@M'vy's idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92067/260841) of having a basic format of `[SITE:type:id]`, and works the same way across the network.

Links are expanded at POST time, so readers don't need to have the extension installed to see or use the links.

> Where
>
> - `SITE` is SF, SO, SU, meta, metaSU with default to the current site
> - `type` can be user, post, faq with default to post
> - `id` can be the id of a post, of an user and anchor a HTML anchor like in the FAQ, or a comment, or a anwser.
>
> You can only use default values from the left. If you specify SITE you have to specify all.

(quoted from his post)

`SITE` can be `su`, `so`, `sf`, or any other SE site by using their API sitename (the thing before `.stackexchange.com`), eg. [`pets`], `[chess]` will expand to the link to that site.

`type` (followed by `anchor`) can be `user` (followed by user id), `post` (followed by post id), `help` (followed by help page name in URL), or `priv` (followed by priv name in URL).

### Install it from [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/shu8/6c7979a4e5861c2e234301cbfa504628/raw/b815629bc1b07d1511435cd72fec72d9a8c66b04/magicLinkEnhancer.user.js)

(or [view the source](https://gist.github.com/shu8/6c7979a4e5861c2e234301cbfa504628))

---

Examples (if posted in a comment on this site):

- `[274240]` => `[Adding magic link for Meta Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274240)`
- `[so:post:1732348]` => `[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348)`
- `[so:post:1732454]` => `[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)`
- `[meta.so:post:321111]` => `[How to help less-skilled developers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321111)`
- `[user:260841]` => `[ᔕᖺᘎᕊ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/260841/%e1%94%95%e1%96%ba%e1%98%8e%e1%95%8a)`
- `[pets:priv:trusted-user]` => `[trusted user](//pets.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)`
- `[stackapps:help:dont-ask]` => `[Help Center](//stackapps.com/help/dont-ask)`
- `[help:dont-ask]` => `[Help Center](http://meta.stackexchange.com)`
- `[meta.so]` => `[Meta Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com)`