# Are magic links broken, or am I using them wrong?

Tags: support, comments, help-center, magic-links

Twice in the past two days, on AU and Math.SE, I've tried to make some comments using [Magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/310919), which I want to come out like this:

> As it currently stands, this does not provide an answer to the question. See [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) — cat

But, if I put the following in the comment box:

```
As it currently stands, this does not provide an answer to the question. 
See [help/how-to-answer]
```

then the result is:

> As it currently stands, this does not provide an answer to the question. See [help/how-to-answer] — cat

I also tried with `[help/on-topic]` and `[help/dont-ask]` with the same result.

Is this a bug or broken, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Hmm, I think you should've used `[answer]` and `[ask]`.

Comment: `[help/on-topic]`, `[help/dont-ask]` and `[help/behavior]` are the only ones supported (and only in comments) - I am using them here: [help/on-topic] [help/dont-ask] [help/behavior]

Comment: @PhMgBr Then http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/310919 is misleading

Comment: @Oded Oh, that probably helps.

Comment: More, and more consistent, magic links would be useful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274240/215590

Comment: @PolyGeo Agreed!

Comment: My greatest accomplishment.

Comment: @Won't What is?

Comment: Go, gaze upon my work, and be humbled.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92060/1228

Comment: @Won't Ooh. :D I should make a [tag:feature-request] for all the help center pages to have magic links