# `[metaso]` expanding to MSE instead of MSO

Tags: support, bug, meta, magic-links

See my comment below. Since [Meta Stack Exchange was separated from Meta Stack Overflow in 2014](/q/228888), it <s>no longer</s> never makes sense to expand `[metaso]` to Meta Stack Exchange.

Also there's currently no magic link for MSO (`[mso]`, `[meta.so]`, `[so.meta]` do not exist), so it'd be convenient and **reasonable** to redirect `[metaso]` to MSO, and alternatively make `[mso]` work. [Adding magic link for Meta Stack Overflow?](/q/274240)

Comment: `[MetaSO]` is expanding to [MetaSO]. And [mso] [meta.so] [so.meta] do not exist.

Comment: Related/dupe of [Adding magic link for Meta Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274240/adding-magic-link-for-meta-stack-overflow)

Comment: @Elephant Related. Not dupe.

Comment: I think that both `[metaso]` and `[meta.so]` should expand to Meta Stack Overflow and `[meta.su]` should expand to Meta Super User.